# Add all vue components to window array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I currently have a strange Vue setup due to our websites all using an old system.

What we have had to do is create an instance of Vue for each component (usually not many). What I want to do for all components is to pass their name and reference to the element into an array, just for reference when debugging issues on live issues.

**app.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Axios from 'axios';
import inViewportDirective from 'vue-in-viewport-directive';

window.components = [];

Vue.component( 'video-frame', () => import('./components/VideoFrame.vue' /* webpackChunkName: "video-frame" */) );

Vue.prototype.$event = new Vue();
Vue.prototype.$http = Axios;

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".app"), (el, index) => new Vue({el}));
```

Now i'm adding the following code to each component, is there not a way I can do this once within my **app.js** and have all the components automatically do the following:

```
mounted() {
    window.components.push({
        tag: this.$vnode.tag,
        elm: this.$vnode.elm
    });
},
```

Comment: The easiest way I can think of is wrapping the entire page in a single parent component, and using `$children` to keep track of the others

Comment: @Ayrton yeah this is the issue we have, we can't do this due to the amount of HTML on legacy websites.

Comment: so you cant use a mixin because you recreate the Vue instance every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global mixin like this:

```
Vue.mixin({
    mounted: function() {
        window.components.push({
            tag: this.$vnode.tag,
            elm: this.$vnode.elm
        });
    }
});
```

That will ensure that code will run on the mounted hook on every single one of your Vue instances.

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Comment: Doesn't appear that the component's are being created in time, getting the following error `Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'tag' of undefined"`

Comment: I had the mixin code above where I create each Vue component, putting it below this works. Thanks.